# How to alter/add to Django's ListView's response headers?

Tags: python, django, listview, httpresponse

I am trying to modify the response headers of a `ListView` in order to solve what seems to be a caching problem. Here is what I am trying:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MapListView, self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)  # Errors here
    response = super(MapListView, self).render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    return response
```

I also tried it with:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data()  # Errors here
    [. . . ]
```

In either situation, this `AttributeError` is thrown:

```
'MapListView" object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

This is apparently happening on this line of `get_context_data()` from `MultipleObjectMixin`:

```
queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
```

What should I be doing differently? How can I alter my `ListView`'s response headers?

---

For reference, here is the [whole `get_context_data()` definition](http://pastebin.com/3Sp1Tz5j).

---

For even more reference, here is my whole view:

```
class MapContactClientListView(ListView):
    model = Map # Note: This isn't the real name, so it's not a problem with this.
    cursor = connections["default"].cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT map.*
                      FROM map
                      INNER JOIN profile
                          ON (map.profile_id = profile.id)
                      ORDER BY profile.name""")
    queryset = dictfetchall(cursor)
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = 'onboardingWebApp/map_list.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MapListView, self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        response = super(MapListView, self).render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
        response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
        return response
```

Comment: It would help if you show the entire Class definition, but from the sounds of it, you never configured a `model` or `queryset`.

Comment: I did configure both. :/ I added the whole definition now.

Comment: Move all that stuff about cursor and queryset into a get_queryset() function (and use return instead of setting queryset). I'm surprised you're not getting an error on those directly.

Comment: Did all that, and...it fixed the problem I was originally working on! :D I still get the same error if I leave in the code under `get`, but without it there, and with the other code in `get_gueryset()`, my caching problem is solved! :D

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what was happening with the issue you were having with `get`, but glad to know that moving the queryset setup into `get_queryset` fixed the original issue and you don't need to worry about overriding headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

```
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(MapListView, self).get(request,*args,**kwargs)
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    return response
```

The call to super().get() will properly set up object_list, but it is dependent on get_queryset. I do not believe you have properly set up your queryset (since you're dynamically setting it up in the class definition), so I would change that to:

```
 def get_queryset(self):
     cursor = connections["default"].cursor()
     cursor.execute("""SELECT map.*
                  FROM map
                  INNER JOIN profile
                      ON (map.profile_id = profile.id)
                  ORDER BY profile.name""")
    return dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Even though I didn't end up needing it, this is very good to know for future reference. :)